# Primefaces Datatable + Row Expansion with updating component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, joinfaces

I have a datatable that has a collection of objects that is initialized on page load. It is not lazy loaded.

In this datatable row, I have a row expansion object that I wish to "toggle" depending on a boolean value for the object in that row (inputSwitch tag in Primefaces). Once that is toggled, I update the DOM and render the sub collection using the "rendered" attribute for the rowExpansion (which I suspect might be the problem, because I think that requires a DOM refresh)

However, whenever I hit the first inputSwitch (the main toggle), it reloads the entire collection and wipes out the changes that have been made.

```
                                    <p:dataTable 
                                        id="myTable"
                                        var="row" 
                                        reflow="true"
                                        expandedRow="true"
                                        filteredValue="#{mybean.filteredAllObjects}"
                                        value="#{mybean.allObjects}">

                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputSwitch value="#{row.boolSelected}">
                                                <p:ajax update=":myform:myTable"/>
                                            </p:inputSwitch>
                                        </p:column>
                                        
                                        <p:rowExpansion rendered="#{row.boolSelected}">
                                            <ui:repeat value="#{row.subsetCollection}" var="subsetRow">
                                                        <p:inputSwitch value="#{subsetRow.boolSelected}"/>
                                            </ui:repeat>
                                        </p:rowExpansion>
                                    </p:dataTable>
```

How can I essentially keep the state of the collection on the client side without the need to re-render the collection (and thus eliminating all changes)?

**Edit**

Backing bean (simplified - it's really this simplistic). When the ajax call is made in the front end, the getter for the collection is called (breakpoint confirms this). Also see a POST is happening, so a call to the server is made:

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<MyObject> allObjects;
    private List<MyObject> filteredAllObjects;

    public MyBean(@Value("#{param['id']}") String selectedId) 
    {
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        allObjects = ... // call to get objects from DB
    }

    // Setters & Getters
```

}

Comment: I will add the bean. It is view scoped (Joinfaces).

Comment: Also - JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6.2 for information purposes

Comment: You are correct the `renderered` attribute requires a DOM refresh.

Comment: And for your complex use case you might have to use Jquery and do it with JavaScript and keep the state on the client side and then remove the row togglers using JS code.

Comment: @Melloware - That's exactly what I ended up doing (I just wrapped it up this morning). I controlled everything via Javascript and CSS. Worked like a charm.

Comment: can you post your JS solution as the solution so others can see and I will give it a bump!

Comment: Absolutely - Will follow up as soon as I can